# I want my function to pause working till the player clicks required number of buttons and then go to next line

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and I am developing Simon game. I just cant figure out how to pause my `evaluate()` function such that after all the blinks are made let the player click few buttons and then check whether they are in correct sequence as produced in `checkBlink()`

```
function evaluate(){

    score = blinks;
    document.getElementById("show_score").value = score;

    // here random blinks are created and change their colors accordingly;
    generateBlink();

    // a function to pause the function till player clicks required number of buttons
    checkBlink();//this function will then check whether the clicked buttons are correct and proceed
}
```

Comment: Are you giving the user a certain time limit to press the buttons?

Comment: If you are using ES6 generator function can be single steped. and Do Next on it to execute chunk of code inside of function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the player a certain amount of time to press the buttons, you should use a **[timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** that will wait and then run your `checkBlink` function:

```js
function evaluate(){

    //score = blinks;
    //document.getElementById("show_score").value = score;
    
    //generateBlink(); //here random blinks are created and change their colors accordingly;
    
    // a function to pause the function till player clicks required number of buttons
    setTimeout(checkBlink, 3000); // Wait 3 seconds and then call checkBlink
    
}

function checkBlink(){
  alert("Time's up!");
}

evaluate();
```

Comment: Alternatively (or in addition), you might want to add a click listener to each of the buttons that pushes the respective color to an array and calls a function to check in the array if all the buttons have been pressed in the correct order.